# web2py sqlform.grid search

Tags: web2py

I use search in SQLFORM.grid. If you want to find empty dates, nothing happens, since the query generated in sqlhtml.py (subquery variable, line 2429) contains "= NULL", while "IS NULL" is correct. Am I doing something wrong or is this a mistake?

web2py 2.9.12
mySQL 5.6.36

Answer (score 0):

If you use search in `SQLFORM.grid` you can use as follows.

```
tablename.datefiled = "\"""
```

so backslash \ will prevent delimeters with "" null condition